# How to select a specific bullet in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have many bullets in a Word document. 
I want to select only a specific bullet i.e. `u)` and make its text red.
I manage to count number of bullets. But I am not sure how to select a specific bullet.

```
Sub FindBullet()

Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim count As Integer
count = 0

'Select Entire document
Selection.WholeStory

With Selection
    For Each oPara In .Paragraphs
        If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListSimpleNumbering Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
End With
'Gives the count of bullets in a document
MsgBox count

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Selection.WholeStory
With Selection
    For Each oPara In .Paragraphs
        If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering Then _
            If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString = "u)" Then _
                oPara.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    Next
End With
```

You're only missing the `Liststring` property which returns the `Numbering` value.
Hope this helps.